# Question Regarding Fetching Records based on Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT COUNT(td.timeSheetID) FROM TimeSheet t 
INNER JOIN TimeSheetDetail td ON t.timeSheetID = td.timeSheetID 
WHERE (CONVERT(DateTime, t.setDate, 23) BETWEEN '2012-08-10' AND '2012-08-12') 
AND t.employeeID = 300
```

The above code returns the value i'm looking for. However, when i do the following, i get nothing:

```
    SELECT COUNT(td.timeSheetID) FROM TimeSheet t INNER JOIN TimeSheetDetail td ON t.timeSheetID = td.timeSheetID 
    WHERE (CONVERT(DateTime, t.setDate, 23) = '2012-08-11') 
    AND t.employeeID = 300
```

setDate value in table looks as:

2012-08-11 18:00:19.000

**My questions:**

1. Why the code in first scenario works fine whereas in the second one doesn't work?
2. Why the code in the first scenario doesn't return a value when i put the actual range as BETWEEN '2012-08-11' AND '2012-08-11' ... How can i solve the problem, i don't time to be considered during the range/filtering. I'm only considered about date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't write queries that use functions on columns to compare with constants. It makes them un-SARG-able and an eventual index on the `setDate` column cannot be used.
- Don't use literals where you can use a parameter
- If you must use literals for datetime, use the [unseparated string format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx#UnseparatedStringFormat) as is not language dependent and is *always* interpreted as `ymd`.

In conclusion:

```
SELECT COUNT(td.timeSheetID) FROM TimeSheet t 
INNER JOIN TimeSheetDetail td ON t.timeSheetID = td.timeSheetID 
WHERE t.setDate BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo 
AND t.employeeID = @employeeId;
```

or (worse):

```
SELECT COUNT(td.timeSheetID) FROM TimeSheet t 
INNER JOIN TimeSheetDetail td ON t.timeSheetID = td.timeSheetID 
WHERE t.setDate BETWEEN '20120810' AND '20120812'
AND t.employeeID = 300;
```

As for your question, the best way to scan a 'day' in a datetime range is to express the day as a range:

```
SELECT COUNT(td.timeSheetID) FROM TimeSheet t 
INNER JOIN TimeSheetDetail td ON t.timeSheetID = td.timeSheetID 
WHERE t.setDate >= '20120811' AND t.setDate < '20120812'
AND t.employeeID = 300;
```

This will cover all hours of 20120811. Is it still better to parameters instead of literals, of course.

And finally, the real question will be if you have a covering index for this query. Time series, like a 'timesheet' table, are almost *always* interogated by daterange, so a clustered index by `(employeeID, setDate)` is probably a good choice. A second best choice is a nonclustered index on the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `CONVERT` and change the value to a DATETIME, the time is not removed.  So the compare to the date values will not match.  Try the following to see what happens

```
SELECT CONVERT(DateTime, t.setDate, 23)
FROM TimeSheet t
```

To drop the time from datetime change the `CONVERT` expression so that the result casts to a varchar data type

```
CONVERT(varchar, t.setDate, 23)
```